# Raspbian - How to open a specific folder path in File Manager using Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspbian

I have been unable to figure out how to open the file manager with a specific path within a python3 script. I have figured out the Python3 part and will use subprocess to use the command, however I haven't managed to make any progress with the terminal command.

Comment: have you tried: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244970/opening-current-directory-from-a-terminal-onto-a-file-browser